# C++: inherited classes have pure virtual functions with identical names. How can I override them separately in my base class?

Tags: c++, function, class, inheritance

The following code illustrates my question:

```
namespace foo1
{
    class bar1
    {
        public:
        virtual void fn() = 0; //this must remain pure virtual
    };
};

namespace foo2
{
    class bar2
    {
        public:
        virtual void fn() = 0; //this must remain pure virtual
    };
};

class bar3: public foo1::bar1, public foo2::bar2
{
    public:

    //can i separately override virtual functions from inherited 
    //classes that have the same name?

    void foo1::bar1::fn() override {std::cout << "bar1";} //error
    void foo2::bar2::fn() override {std::cout << "bar2";} //error
};

int main()
{
    bar3* obj = new bar3();

    ((foo1::bar1*)obj)->fn(); //i want this to print "bar1"
    ((foo2::bar2*)obj)->fn(); //and this to print "bar2"
}
```

Basically I want to be able to override inherited functions, such that by simply casting my base class object to one of the inherited classes, I can call the different functions even though they have the same name. Is this possible?

Comment: You would need to add intermediate classes to do renaming of virtual functions (that is `fn` would call virtual `fn1` in `bar1rename` and same thing for bar2). Then inherit from `bar1rename` and `bar2rename` and override the renamed functions. But **you should not do that as it make code hard to understand** and maintain. Better to rename `fn` in one base class...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the inherited classes in this case are from separate APIs which I cannot change. It's not ideal obviously but the intermediate class at least seems workable.

Comment: Intermediate base classes are a common workaround, if you have two bases each providing the same function (same name, argument types, and return type), and cannot change the original base classes.

Comment: By the way, maybe  you should have used aggregation (or composition) instead of multiple inheritance and avoid the problem in a possibly cleaner and easier to understand way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
struct foo1bar1helper:public foo1::bar1{
  void fn()final{foo1bar1fn();}
  virtual void foo1bar1fn()=0;
};
```

now `bar3` just inherits from this instead of `bar1` and overrides `foo1bar1fn()`,

Do the same with `bar2`.

You can also use CRTP to dispatch and do away with the extra vtable lookup;

```
template<class D>
struct foo1bar1helper:public foo1::bar1{
  void fn()final{static_cast<D*>(this)->foo1bar1fn();}
};

template<class D>
struct foo2bar2helper:public foo2::bar2{
  void fn()final{static_cast<D*>(this)->foo2bar2fn();}
};

class bar3:
  public foo1bar1helper<bar3>,
  public foo2bar2helper<bar3>
{
public:
  void foo1bar1fn(){}
  void foo2bar2fn(){}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that. When you do foo1::bar1::fn(), compiler thinks that you are defining function fn of 'bar1' of 'foo1' namespace in class bar3. Hence compiler is throwing below error.

```
error: cannot define member function ‘foo1::bar1::fn’ within ‘bar3’
```

But when you extend from an abstract class, you need to give the definition of the function (which should be part of your derived class) in derived class.